# Angular JS injector:modulerr

Tags: angularjs

I have just started working on angular js. It's showing an error mentioned below.It works fine when the js code is placed inside html page itself using script tag, **but when it is placed in external javascript file it's showing error below. Can any one help me out. I have pasted the code here.** I am using angularJS one v1.5.7

Error:

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mainApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'mainApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/nomod?p0=mainApp
    at file:///D:/Tutorials/AnjularjS/Controllers/lib/angular.js:68:12
    at file:///D:/Tutorials/AnjularjS/Controllers/lib/angular.js:2075:17
    at ensure (file:///D:/Tutorials/AnjularjS/Controllers/lib/angular.js:1999:38)
    at module (file:///D:/Tutorials/AnjularjS/Controllers/lib/angular.js:2073:14)
    at file:///D:/Tutorials/AnjularjS/Controllers/lib/angular.js:4608:22
    at forEach (file:///D:/Tutorials/AnjularjS/Controllers/lib/angular.js:321:20)
    at loadModules (file:///D:/Tutorials/AnjularjS/Controllers/lib/angular.js:4592:5)
    at createInjector (file:///D:/Tutorials/AnjularjS/Controllers/lib/angular.js:4514:19)
    at doBootstrap (file:///D:/Tutorials/AnjularjS/Controllers/lib/angular.js:1751:20)
    at bootstrap (file:///D:/Tutorials/AnjularjS/Controllers/lib/angular.js:1772:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=mainApp&p1=Error%3A…FD%3A%2FTutorials%2FAnjularjS%2FControllers%2Flib%2Fangular.js%3A1772%3A12)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:68(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4631forEach @ angular.js:321loadModules @ angular.js:4592createInjector @ angular.js:4514doBootstrap @ angular.js:1751bootstrap @ angular.js:1772angularInit @ angular.js:1657(anonymous function) @ angular.js:31468trigger @ angular.js:3198defaultHandlerWrapper @ angular.js:3488eventHandler @ angular.js:3476
```

HTML PART:

```
<html>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <head>
      <title>Angular JS Controller</title>

      <script src = "lib/angular.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>

      <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="studentController">
         Enter first name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "student.firstName"><br><br>
         Enter last name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "student.lastName"><br>
         <br>

         You are entering: {{student.fullName()}}
      </div>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
      <!--
      <script>
       var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

         mainApp.controller('studentController', function($scope) {
            $scope.student = {
               firstName: "Mahesh",
               lastName: "Parashar",

               fullName: function() {
                  var studentObject;
                  studentObject = $scope.student;
                  return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
               }
            };
         });
      </script>
      -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Js:

```
function initData()
{
    console.log("Entered initData:");
    ajsController();
}
function ajsController()
{

         var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

         mainApp.controller('studentController',function($scope) {
            $scope.student = {
               firstName: "Mahesh",
               lastName: "Parashar",

               fullName:function() {
                  var studentObject;
                  studentObject = $scope.student;
                  return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
               }
            };
         });

}
```

Comment: The problem is `ng-app` is asking for `mainApp ` module before your function call, 1st thing why you are intializing angular component on function call? If you want to stick with this approach, then remove `ng-app` & use `bootstrap` application lazily

Comment: please pradeepkumar don't place js content inside the functions.

Comment: Hi thank you got the answer it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `app.js` file in lib folder

```
<script src = "lib/app.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("mainApp", []);

         app.controller('studentController', function($scope) {
            $scope.student = {
               firstName: "Mahesh",
               lastName: "Parashar",

               fullName: function() {
                  var studentObject;
                  studentObject = $scope.student;
                  return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
               }
            };
         });
```

**html**

```
<html>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <head>
      <title>Angular JS Controller</title>

      <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/app.js"></script>

   </head>

   <body>
      <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>

      <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="studentController">
         Enter first name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "student.firstName"><br><br>
         Enter last name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "student.lastName"><br>
         <br>

         You are entering: {{student.fullName()}}
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot. Tht works. I have have even made the my code posted work, just has to put the function call before ng-app..you answer helped me to understand the flow how it works... as you said it's more about right way(approach)...nearly three to four hour searched reason for it...once again thanks a lot  :)

Answer (score 0):

You've put your module creation code inside the function ajsController, called from initData, but I don't see you calling initData() anywhere?

Comment: Hi, thank you, i forget that piece of code. But the error still exists.It's not recognize my mainApp module...which it does when placed in html page inside script tag

Comment: Did you check that your `script.js` file is inside the `js` folder?